# Online Glossary of Second Language Acquisition Terms

Tags: resource-request

I am looking for an **online glossary of second language acquisition (SLA) terms** that fulfils the following **criteria**:

- It was created by SLA researchers or teaching professionals. ([This one on Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/58436642/glossary-second-language-acquisition-research-and-second-language-teaching-flash-cards/) has a pseudonym as author, so I don't know if it was created by a researcher or a language teacher.)
- It does not focus exclusively on teaching English as a foreign language.
- It does not only cover acronyms (like this [glossary of acronyms](http://www.teaching-english-in-japan.net/acronyms/)) but also "normal" terms (e.g. "elaborate encoding").
- It is not limited to a specific teaching method such as communicative language teaching (like this [glossary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_language_education_terms)).

The resources need not be in English; it can also be in German, French, Spanish or Dutch.

If the glossary is in English, we can refer LL SE contributors to it if we think they misunderstand some of the terms used on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Glossary on Language Learning and Teaching](http://genius-ja.uz.ua/sites/default/files/csatolmanyok/magyar-nyelvu-oktatasi-jegyzetek-es-magyar-nyelvu-szaknyelvi-szotarak-nyerteseinek-dokumentumjai-472/glossaryonlanguageteachingandlearninghusztiilona.pdf) by Ilona Huszti
- [Scott Thornbury's blog](https://scottthornbury.wordpress.com/). Not exactly a glossary; it looks like it's meant to be a sort of appendix and update to Thornbury's actual ELT glossary published in a book form. Written from the perspective of teaching English, but useful to readers interested in general theories of learning and teaching foreign languages. Some of the entries aren't closely related to SLA, and sometimes it's not clear where things are, e.g. the comprehensible output hypothesis is described under "Push".
- Glossaries in some SLA books are partly viewable online. For example, parts of glossaries in textbooks by Rod Ellis can be accessed through [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019437212X) and [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=3KglibyrZ5sC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Scott Thornbury's list looks more like an index to his blog than a glossary: wabi-sabi is not an SLA term, the entry for Krashen tells you almost nothing about Krashen's theories, etc. So I hope that people will keep looking for other glossaries.

Comment: You've got a point. I think it's something between a blog and an appendix to the actual glossary he published. I updated my answer and added one more link that you may like better.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few more glossaries:

- [Ask an Expert: NCELA FAQ](http://www.ncela.us/files/rcd/BE021775/Glossary_of_Terms.pdf) by the National Clearinghouse for English Language Acquisition (NCELA).
- [Glossaire hypertextuel de didactique du FLE](http://portail-du-fle.info/glossaire/index.html) by Manfred Overmann, a teacher of French.
- [Glossary of Didactic Terms](http://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/englischesseminar/tefl/glossary_of_didactic_terms.pdf) (University of Münster, Germany).